# Autoviz: Run online / easily set up Python environment

Tags: python-3.x

I want to use the autoviz package so that I can easily analyse some of my data. I use the latest MacOS operating system and have the most recent Python version installed. When trying to install it with `pip3 install autoviz`, I get an error message (console log below). I also tried to find an online environment to quickly get it running, but it seems that https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter/lab/ and https://www.online-python.com do not easily support it.

Thus, I wanted to kindly enquire if you can recommend another easy way (ideally another online IDE) that easily supports running the Autoviz module.

Many thanks!

Here is the console output:

```
% pip3 install autoviz
```

Fails at:

```
 File "/private/var/folders/b0/c35yv5914h11td2v5ycnmj340000gp/T/pip-build-env-1bhatael/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
import distutils.core
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

% pip3 install setuptools
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-69.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
Downloading setuptools-69.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (821 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 821.5/821.5 kB 2.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: setuptools
Successfully installed setuptools-69.2.0
Collecting numpy<1.25.0 (from autoviz)
  Using cached numpy-1.24.4.tar.gz (10.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          backend = _build_backend()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "/private/var/folders/b0/c35yv5914h11td2v5ycnmj340000gp/T/pip-build-env-u72zpcn2/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
          import setuptools.version
        File "/private/var/folders/b0/c35yv5914h11td2v5ycnmj340000gp/T/pip-build-env-u72zpcn2/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
          import pkg_resources
        File "/private/var/folders/b0/c35yv5914h11td2v5ycnmj340000gp/T/pip-build-env-u72zpcn2/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2172, in <module>
          register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Run autoviz online

Go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements#python-environment-with-a-requirementstxt) and click the '`launch binder`' badge. Once the **temporary** session starts up, open a new notebook file and in the top cell, run the following

```py
%pip install autoviz
```

Let that run to completion. It will take several minutes as this is a very complex installation with a lot of dependencies.

After that restart the kernel and try the import statement `from autoviz import AutoViz_Class`. If that works, the installation was successful. At least in the base sense. I suspect though you should also refresh your browser page as I am expecting it involves some complex display handling that the `pip` install step won't yet propagate the settings fullly to the underlying tech without a refresh of the page itself.

Once that refresh happens, you should be ready to actually use autoviz.

See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/writing-jupyter-notebooks/24453/2?u=fomightez) to understand better why Try Jupyter didn't work well for this use case (because it runs with JupyterLite) and why you should use the MyBinder service for a better online Jupyter/Python experience.
Additionally, that page points out some caveats to be aware of while using temporary Jupyter sessions served via the MyBinder service.
Plus, it discusses how to upload your own content to the temporary, anonymous session.

##### Run autoviz on your local system

I suspect installing [the Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/download) would be the easiest route.

After installing that, **make sure you read the Anaconda 'Getting Started' material** as this Python Distribution/package manager-system is more complex than just installing Jupyter. I would suggest making a new environment for autoviz and that this can require extra steps to get Jupyter to use that environment. (You can also use the same command below to install autoviz to base, I think if you just open the Anaconda Navigator and start a flavor of the Jupyter interface without first making an environment.)

In your notebook there you can run the following to install it to the correct environment:

```py
%conda install conda-forge::autoviz
```